# django tag 'get_recent_articles' received too many positional arguments

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a recent article list in the sidebar of my blog. So I make a tag in templatetags.
I use django1.8 and python2.7.
templatetags/blog_tags.py

```
from ..models import Article,Category
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_recent_articles(num=5):
    return Article.objects.all()[:num]
```

base.html

```
{% load blog_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<div class="widget widget-recent-posts">        
    <h3 class="widget-title">recent</h3>
        {% get_recent_articles as article_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for article in article_list %}
        <li>
        <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I runserver,Template error,Traceback display the problem line is {% get_recent_articles as article_list %}

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/index/
'get_recent_articles' received too many positional arguments
```

How do I solve this error? Please give me some advices.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean `with get_recent_articles as article_list` ?

Answer (score 3):

The ability for simple tags to store their results in a variable was added in Django 1.9.

In previous versions, you should use the [`assignment_tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.assignment_tag) decorator instead.